# How to sort a vector <char*>?

Tags: c++, string, sorting, vector

```
#include <algorithm>

bool comparisonFunc(char* c1, char* c2)
{
     return strcmp(c1, c2) ? 0 : 1;
}

vector<char*> myVec;
vector<char*>::iterator itr;
sort(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), comparisonFunc)
```

Is that correct or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: `itr` appears to be unused.  And `strcmp(...) ? 0 : 1` would be more idiomatically written `!strcmp(...)`.  But I don't know the answer to your actual question.

Comment: @user1002288 Why dont you use `std::sort(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), ::strcmp);` directlt?

Comment: Note: `strcmp` returns -1, 0, or +1 depending on whether c1 is <, =, or > c2.  Hence, you need `strcmp(lhs, rhs) < 0` to do a less-than sort.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::sort`expects a "less than" predicate. You should implement your `comparisonFunc()` like this:

```
bool comparisonFunc(const char *c1, const char *c2)
{
    return strcmp(c1, c2) < 0;
}
```

(Note the `const`s; they are important.)

Your current implementation couldn't possibly work because you just return if the values are equal or not. That information is not enough to sort - you need to know which one is smaller and which one is bigger (unless, of course, the values are equal).

Comment: why const is important here ?

Comment: std::sort would never let you modify the contents of the container when it just wants to know which one is smaller.

Comment: How about bool comparisonFunc(const char* c1, const char* c2) const {} ?

Comment: The last `const` is only necessary/allowed if the function is a member function of a class (a method in Java-speak). Basically the last `const` after the parameters makes the `this` pointer `const`

Comment: Why not `std::sort(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), ::strcmp);` directly?

Comment: `strcmp()` is **not** less-than.  It can't be used directly as a predicate for ordering.

Answer (score 0):

With modern C++, you can define the comparison method inline:

```
std::vector<const char*> strings;
/* fill strings vector */
std::sort(strings.begin(), strings.end(), [](const char* lhs, const char* rhs) {
    return strcmp(lhs, rhs) < 0;
});
```

Note that `strcmp` returns -1/0/+1 to indicate ordinality, hence the `< 0` comparison.

Answer (score -1):

I more often want to sort a vector of pointer to records than just plain C-strings...

```
    template<>
    struct std::less<const foo*>
    {
       bool operator()(const foo* lhs, const foo* rhs) const
       {
          return strcmp(lhs->key, rhs->key);
       }
    };
```

This redefines comparison of foo* such that the default comparison works in the sort. To me this style feels more declarative, the other more procedural. If you need multiple orderings this use of the default is problematic; if you want to be sure that all ordered collections of foo*s are in the same order it's good.

```
std::vector<foo*> db;
std::sort(db.begin(), db.end());
```

Comment: Don't you mean `return strcmp(...) < 0;` ?

Comment: IMO, this is rather problematic. You make `foo_p1 < foo_p2` and `std::less<const foo*>()(foo_p1, foo_p2)` behave differently, and in addition the latter has a different result than `std::less<foo*>()(foo_p1, foo_p2)`.

Comment: ... and the standard does not even seem to suggest that sorting algorithms should use std::less by default. Your snippet is full of errors and needn't work at all at the end of the day.

Comment: UH my bad on strcmp(), sorry. What does the standard say about where it finds a default for T < T? Could it be... std::less(T)?

Comment: Defining operator< for non-class items such as T* is problematic as can be. This is how it's _possible_.